# Should you pass setter functions into the dependency array of a React hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Recently I saw a few examples of passing setter functions into hook dependency arrays in my coworkers' React code, and it doesn't look right to me. For example:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomeBigLongNetworkRequest();
    setLoading(false);
  }, [setLoading, /* other deps */]);
  // ...
}
```

My feeling is that they have misunderstood the purpose of the dependency array, which, as I understand it, is to indicate *which pieces of state to monitor* so that the hook can fire again when they change, *not* to simply indicate that the hook needs to use the `setLoading` function. And since the `setLoading` function never actually changes, including it in the dependencies does nothing.

Am I correct, or does including the setter in the array make sense somehow? My other thought was that maybe this was just a linter error, since the linter cannot recognize that the function is a setter, and thinks it might change.

I should also add that in the instances I've seen, they've included the setter but *not* the variable. So in the example above, `setLoading`, but not `loading` would be in the dependency array, and the hook does not actually need the value of `loading`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you are right there is no need to include them. Here is quote from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect
> or useCallback dependency list.

In general again based on [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) the recommendation about dependency array is:

> If you use this optimization, make sure the array includes all values
> from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over
> time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will
> reference stale values from previous renders.

Comment: Agreed! But, why the linter indicates that we need to put setter fxns. in the dep array? 

Comment: @CodeFinity Are you sure that it does? It would be strange because like I cited in the answer official docs say there is no need to.

Comment: Yes. I have a GIF that I made, but NS how to share that here, but yes, definitely. Your answer is precisely why I have been confused about this. I just add them in to the dep array as it's not a big deal to do so, but from Day 1 of using `useEffect` it hasn't made sense that a setter fxn. would be treated like state that would need to be listed. ‍♂️

Comment: @CodeFinity maybe you create-react-app is old, no warning here:https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-wave-zkkf5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Probably. It occurs to me that the project in question was created a while back.